# how do I find an orthonormal basis for a set of linearly dependent vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality, orthonormal

Consider inner product space $\mathbb{R}^4$ with respect to the dot product.

Find an orthonormal basis for the subspace $W$ of $\mathbb{R}^4$ generated by:

$\left\lbrace
\begin{bmatrix}
4\\2\\6\\-2
\end{bmatrix},
 \begin{bmatrix}
1\\-1\\3\\-1
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\2\\0\\0
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\5\\-3\\1
\end{bmatrix}
\right\rbrace $

Ok so I tried using Gram-Schmidt, however, these vectors are linearly dependent. I've read somewhere that Gram-Schmidt can only be applied to a set of linearly independent vectors..is this true? I end up getting two zero vectors in my set of orthogonal vectors! Is this against the rules? Please help!

Please be very elaborate as I have searched everywhere for help!

Comment: You have to remove vectors so the remaining set is linearly independent

Comment: what do you mean remove vectors

Comment: For instance the first three are linearly independent, so remove the last vector and the subspace is the one spanned by the remaining vectors

Comment: so you are saying use gram schmidt on the first three vectors and thats my answer?...the set of 3 orthogonal vectors i get at the end? after I normalize them?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I'm saying

Comment: i still dont understand how a set of 3 vectors spans a 4-dimensional space

Comment: It doesn't is spans a 3D subspace of a 4D space

Comment: is it because of the spanning set theorem?

Comment: Even though the vectors live in a 4d space, even though there are 4 of them, even though between them they have nonzero entries in all 4 components, still it is possible and indeed the case that they don't span all 4 dimensions.

Comment: OKAY SO THE SUBSPACE W = $\mathbb{R}^{3}$?!

Comment: The subspace has dimension $3$, which is not the same thing as being literally $\mathbb{R}^3$. We know it's not $\mathbb{R}^3$, since it doesn't contain a single vector with $3$ components!

Comment: oh wow. thank you guys.

Comment: @TopGoober The subspace $W$ is three dimensional, and so it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$... but still we should not say it _is_ $\mathbb{R}^3$, because that usually refers to a very specific subspace. The one spanned by $(1,0,0,0)$, $(0,1,0,0),$ and $(0,0,1,0).$ $W$ is not this subspace, so don't call it $\mathbb{R}^3.$ It's just some generic oblique 3-plane in $\mathbb{R}^4.$

Comment: @TopGoober But, it does have a basis with $3$ vectors, like $\mathbb{R}^3$. It means that the structure is very similar to that of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Sort of like the plane $x + y + z = 0$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is structurally similar to the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$, but they are not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gram-Schmidt can be used to reduce down to a linearly independent basis! Normally, the way it works is you find a vector orthogonal to the vectors so far, then normalise it. This orthogonal vector will be $0$ if and only if the vector was dependent on the previous ones. So, if you get a zero, ignore that vector and move on to the next one.

It works pretty simply, if you understand Gram-Schmidt geometrically. What Gram-Schmidt does is, at stage $j$, project $v_j$ onto the span of $v_1, \ldots v_{j-1}$, and take the orthogonal complement of this projection. When this returns a zero, this means that the projection onto the span coincides with $v_j$ in the first place, which can only happen when $v_j$ belongs in the span to begin with. Thus, removing $v_j$ from the span will not reduce it.